# Trouble Getting User Input in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm newbie and trying to do something pretty basic after reading the Django Doc Project Documentation, but can't seem to figure it out. I'm getting a user's name with a POST and trying to GET it and display it on the same page. I'm getting an error: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'greeting_id'

I'm using Django 2 and wondering if it could be something with the routing? I'm not exactly sure as I'm very new to MVC and Django.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Greeting


# create hello view

def hello(request, greeting_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['firstname']:
            greeting = models.Greeting()
            greeting.firstname = request.POST['firstname']
            greeting.save()
            obj = models.Greeting.objects.get(pk=greeting_id)
            context = {
                'object': obj
            }
        return render(request, 'greetings/home.html', context)
    return render(request, 'greetings/home.html')
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Greeting(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        # returns post object in admin interface
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from greetings import views #import greetings views into the url file

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('hello/', views.hello, name='hello'),
]
```

home.html

```
{% block content %}

<h2>Let's Say Hello!</h2>
<br/>
<br/>

<div>
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'hello' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  Enter your first name:
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="firstname" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="submit">

</form>
{{ object.firstname }}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at most of the code, but just looking at the error message and the 2 relevant parts of the code, it's clear that you've declared a second parameter (other than `request`) to the `hello` view but have no parameter in the corresponding URL. This doesn't make sense and is what Django is complaining about. If you want the response to depend on the value of `greeting_id` you need to provide it in the request - that either means as part of the `POST` data, or as part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your view "hello" requires an parameter "greeting_id"

```
def hello(request, greeting_id):
```

These parameters are passed from the url routing to the view, for the view to work your url would have to look like this

```
path('hello/<int:greeting_id>/', views.hello, name='hello'),
```

Where is greeting_id supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Hi @Iain , thank you. After using your code I now get message: 

Using the URLconf defined in greetingproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
hello/<int:greeting_id>/ [name='hello']
The current path, hello/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: You should remove greeting_id from the url and from your view

Comment: Looks like you added the path given by the answer on to the end of the `/admin` route, rather than replacing the `/hello` one as was meant. (Either that or you added this route to `admin.site.urls`, which seems unlikely.)